# fixed point set of orthogonal action on$ S^n $is again a sphere $S^r$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, group-actions

My question is why for an orthogonal action of G on $S^n$ the fixed point set is again sphere $S^r$

Orthogonal action of G means G has orthogonal representation that is there exist a homeomorphism of G into O(n).

Fixed point set of G on X is the set of those x in X such that  g(x)=x for all g in G

For action of O(3) on $S^2$ the fixed point set is $S^0$ the two point set.but i don't know how to prove it generally .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The fixed point set of a single orthogonal transformation $T$ on a sphere centered at the origin is the intersection of the sphere with the $1$-eigenspace of $T$.

Comment: Slick - I like it!

Comment: Is it true that fixed point set will be always  $S^0$ for orthogonal action on $S^n$?@Andrew D.Hwang

Comment: @prakriti:  No.  Consider the trivial action.  Less trivially, consider a single reflection.

Comment: Your group $G$ could be the trivial group, in which case the fixed point set is the entire sphere, or the group of order $2$ generated by reflection in one axis, in which case the fixed point set is a great hypersphere, or.... :)

Comment: Is it true that If I take full group O(n) then the fixed point set of this action on $S^n$ is $S^0$ ?

Comment: If $G = O(n)$, the fixed-point set is _empty_. :)

Comment: O sorry.I understand my mistake.